# Initializing a variable by a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I am trying to initialize a variable using a lambda expression. I havn't heard if this is possible or not, so is this possible?
For example:

```
int i([]() { return 1; });
```

which returns

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'wmain::<lambda_b35514739a4854f3d329a617eabe58c1>' to 'int'
```

Is this operation possible, and my syntax is merely wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are trying to initialize the variable with the lambda object not with the result of evaluating the lambda:

```
int i([]() { return 1; }());
//                      ^^
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to *call* the lambda:

```
int i( []() { return 1; }() );
                      // ^^
```

The lambda itself is an expression that yiels a a prvalue temporary called a *closure object*. These are not convertible to `int`.